# what causes black artifacts on the surface of a model?

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine, normals, artifacts

So, I'm pretty new at Blender, to say the least. I've followed lots of tutorials and decided I was ready to try modeling something on my own. So far, it's turning out great. I have an issue with some artifacts(?) that show up in the viewport and when rendering with blenders renderer. Cycles renderer is fine.

View port Edit Mode:
[image: View port Edit Mode]
Blender Render:
[image: Blender Render]
As you can see, the Blender Renderer has WAY more artifacts(?) than the view port.

I tried recalculating normals first. That didn't work. Then, I thought it might be because of the hole in the front of the body using the boolean modifier. If you look in the Edit mode pic, you can see some ngons that I've started to fix. If it were the ngons, the ones I've fixed should be rendering fine, right? Also, why would the Blender Renderer have so many artifacts(?) and the Cycles Renderer not have any? I've looked around for the past hour trying to find an answer, but really I'm not even sure I know how to word the question lol.